# Como executar uma função Js que esta ligada a um botão mais de uma vez?

Tags: javascript

Opa galera!

Seguinte tenho uma função no arquivo "Script.js" que retorna uma mensagem formatada com os valores
aleatórios obtidos como segue o exemplo:

Manipulação de dados:

```
let choice = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let resultado = []
resultado.push(choice[Math.floor((Math.random() * choice.length))])
```

Atribuição da saída de dados:

```
let div = document.getElementById("divId")
```

E finalmente a função que apresenta os dados manipulados de uma forma formatada:

```
function Show() {
    let resultado = 'valor obtido = ' + resultado[0]
    div.InnerHTML = resultado
}
```

Até aí ta show, fiz um documento HTML padrão coloquei a div e tudo mais, fiz um botão
e 'bindei' a função **Show()** no **onclick** dentro do documento **Html**, maravilha funcionou
porém o botão é clicável apenas uma vez! Aí vem a minha pergunta, como faço para que ao apertar
o botão novamente ele apresente um resultado diferente dentro das escolhas que ele tem ('a', 'b', 'c')

Comment: De norma botões podem ser clicados multiplas vezes, se o seu botão está funcionando só a primeira vez então deve ter alguma condição e/ou erro que esteja impedindo o normal funcionamento do mesmo.

Comment: Tem certeza que o botão só funciona uma vez? Não é o fato de você estar dando push em um valor fora da função, e chamando a função pra exibir no onClick? Do jeito que tá aí, toda vez que tu clicar vai exibir o mesmo valor, já que tu não tá mudando ele em nenhum lugar. Sugiro botar essa lógica dentro da função. Aí toda vez que tu clicar vai ter um número aleatório diferente

Comment: Perfeito mano! Eu esqueci completamente disso kkkk deu super certo, muito obrigado!